# Can I export documentation from Swimm to Word or PDF?

Tags: export-to-pdf, export-to-word, swimm

hope you're doing well. We're working on code documentation for our EMR product using Swimm and our developer's experience has been phenomenal so far due to ease of access, great UX and so on. Now we need it to be exported to Word or PDF to keep it locally secure instead of being on cloud. Is there any way of it?

I did read documentation and checked pricing plan as well but everywhere, it talks about how to import into Swimm and there is no mention of export anywhere. If it's possible then it'd save a lot of my and developers time for documentation.

Comment: I have not used Swimm myself (which is why I'm posting a comment instead of an answer), but according to their documentation, your content is not stored in the cloud by them. It is stored as markdown files in a `.swm` directory in your own code repository. You can read the contents of those markdown files, and you can probably run them through a processing programs such as pandoc to get a PDF version if you want.